# Surface Integral Proof

Tags: calculus, integration

QUESTION:

Set $B_r = \{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq r\}$, $\mathbb{S}_r = \{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2\}$, $\forall r >0$ and denote $\omega(r)$ to be the area of $\mathbb{S}^2_r, \forall r>0$.

Suppose $u\in C^1(B_1)$, set $I_u(r) = \frac{1}{\omega(r)}\int\int_{\mathbb{S^2_r}}udS, \forall r>0$, show that

$$ \frac{d}{dr}I_u(r) = \frac{1}{\omega(r)}\iint_{\mathbb{S^2_r}}\nabla 
   u\cdot d\vec{S}, \forall 1>r>0. $$

ANSWER:

First parametrize $\mathbb{S}^2_r$ as: 
$$ x = r\cos\theta\sin\phi,\ \  
   y = r\sin\theta\sin\phi, \ \
   z = r\cos\phi $$

$$ 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi\ \text{and}\ 0\leq\phi\leq\pi,\ \ \ \ 
   dS=r^2\sin\phi $$
Since we are in 3-D, the surface area of $\mathbb{S}^2_r$ is simply $\omega(r) = 4\pi r^2$.

Now,

$$ I_u(r) = \frac{1}{4\pi 
r^2}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}u\big(r\cos\theta\sin\phi,r\sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\phi\big)r^2\sin\phi\ d\theta\ d\phi $$

Then by the Chain Rule,

$$ \frac{d}{dr}I_u(r) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^2}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\big(u_x\cos\theta\sin\phi + u_y\sin\theta\sin\phi + u_z\cos\phi\big)r^2\sin\phi\ d\theta\ d\phi $$

$$ \frac{d}{dr}I_u(r) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^2}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}(u_x, u_y, u_z) \cdot (\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\phi)r^2\sin\phi\ d\theta\ d\phi $$

Note that on $\mathbb{S}^2_r$, the outer normal is $\vec{n} = \frac{(x,y,z)}{r}$ therefore,

$$ \frac{d}{dr}I_u(r) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^2}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi} (\nabla u \cdot \vec{n})r^2\sin\phi\ d\theta\ d\phi $$

$$ \frac{d}{dr}I_u(r) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^2}\iint_{\mathbb{S}_r} \nabla u \cdot \vec{n}\ dS $$

$$ \frac{d}{dr}I_u(r) = \frac{1}{\omega(r)}\iint_{\mathbb{S}_r} \nabla u \cdot d\vec{S} $$

Comment: Which part of "Suppose $u\in C^1(B_1)$" is difficult for you?

Comment: I haven't seen that notation before so I'm not sure what it means, I'm guessing it means any point inside the ball of radius < 1?

Comment: Your instructor should have told you what a $C^1$ function is. In this case, $u$ is not a point in the disk; it is a function on the disk whose first first derivative is continuous. Likewise, in part b, a $C^2$ function is a function whose second derivative is continuous.